# how to complete back end for auto complete jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a text box,
Inside I want it to auto complete.
The data for the auto complete is going to be given through the database.

This is my Jquery:

```
 var data = "autocompletetagdata.aspx"
    $("#item").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   return "['word', 'hello', 'work', 'oi', 'hey']";     
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string term = Request.QueryString["term"];
   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
   myConnection.Open();
   string result = "[";
   int i = 0;
   string SQL = ("select LTRIM(RTRIM(PGPRDC)) As PGPRDC FROM SROPRG SROPRG where PGPRDC like '" + term + "%'");
   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   try
      {
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
             result += "";
             result += "\"" + reader.GetString(0) + "\"";                          
             result += ",";
             i += 1;
             sb.Append(reader.GetString(0))
                           .Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
      }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      myConnection.Close();
   }
   result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
   myConnection.Close();
   result += "]";   
   Response.Write(result);  
}
```

Comment: -1 as string concatenation is not guaranteed to generate valid JSON. You need to consider the myriad ways in which the contents of `reader.GetString(0)` may break your output.

Comment: I would seriously consider putting the logic into a Web Method, as you will end up with separate ASPX pages for each AJAX call you're doing... It becomes a nightmare to maintain on a large-scale web application.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$("#item").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "autocompletetagdata.aspx/Search",
            data: { "search": request.term },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (results) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(results);
                response($.map(data, function (item) { 
                    return { value: item } 
                }))
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In your code behind, make it a web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Search(string search)
{
    string[] list = new [] { "word", "hello", "work", "oi", "hey" };

    return list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(search));
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the preferred way to handle this scenario in ASP.NET. The `[WebMethod]` attribute will take care of the correct JSON serialization.

Comment: ^ Agreed. This avoids the necessity to have different pages for every single AJAX call you'll be doing. I generally have an "ajax.aspx" page with the different Web Methods handling the HTML rendering and POST actions I need to do... I don't know why this wasn't accepted as the answer, as it is exactly what I would've recommended as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think what's wrong is you have to return json formatted data and not a comma separated string. Look at the [demos page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote), it says:

> The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data,
>   specified via a simple URL for the source-option.

Comment: The code from Paul's answer should work fine as it's valid json. You can always use something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if you are actually getting this string from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As per: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/jqueryautocomplete.aspx 
try returning a list of strings instead.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> PopSearch()
{
 return new List<string> { "oi", "oi", "hey"};
}
```

Comment: can not be used because ti is part of iso-2 c#

Answer (score 0):

jQuery autocomplete expects json as a result so this will work

```
return "['word', 'hello', 'work', 'oi', 'hey']";
```

For more complex data consider using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing seems to be working for you, make sure you've got the basics covered:

- Are you loading both the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries? (autocomplete is jQuery UI)
- Are you calling your jQuery code inside a DOM ready function?
- Can you hit your web method directly in the browser and get data back?

Comment: all libraries r included and the code id doc ready and i can load the ajax.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete with data is not really all that hard. First you need to establish your return type.  The easiest tends to be in json format so:

*PHP Controller End*

```
// be sure to use echo, not return
echo json_encode($yourDataAsArrayOrObject);
```

With that part done go back to your javascript

```
$("#item").autocomplete({
    // source should be a url to the controller function that returns the data
    source: 'www.yoursite.com/controller/function',
    search: function(e, ui) {}, // here you can manipulate other elements or items while the data is being retrieved,
    select: function(e, ui) { /* ui.item is item slected */ } // here you can manipluate things based on the item that was selected, for instance, save a list of sub data to another dom element
});
```

Finally, the caveat

```
// You will need to use ._renderItem to items as they are received by database.
// For instance, if you want to display the dropdown items in a custom way.
$("#item")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {  
  // the item. depends on the information you got from server
  return ul.append($("<li></li>").prepend($("<h3></h3>").text(item.label)).append($("<p></p>").text(item.value)));
};
```

Comment: ewww, i'm not getting asp on my hands, that's nasty!

Comment: SpYk3HH: no problem, you're entitled to your preferences. Just pay attention to the question so as not to waste your time and ours. Look at the question's sample code and tags before you post your answer for another development platform.

Comment: lol, silly comment to make i know, but seriously, asp or not, _renderItem, appears to be what he is looking for and even his option setup, tho, seriously, more and more companies are moving away from asp programming because of it's lack of feature availability for everything that can be accomplished on simple languages and not cause major "overhead" to the user. Just something to think about. I used to be a huge .Net fan, and thought 4.0 was GREAT, but realistically, MS is just not keeping up with web-standards and more importantly, portable standards.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the data being returned is delimted with single quotes (['word', 'hello', 'work', 'oi', 'hey']) which does not produce valid JSON.

Simply replace the single quotes with double quotes and it should work. Example: 'word' becomes "word". Depending on how you build the string server-side, you may need to escape the double quotes like "[""word"",""hello"", etc

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   return "[""word"", ""hello"", ""work"", ""oi"", ""hey""]";     
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@Troy Barlow, you obviously meant

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] Search(string search)
{
  string[] list = new[] { "word", "hello", "work", "oi", "hey" };
  return list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(search)).ToArray();
}
```